# How to find a text in the uploaded PDF file in ASP.NET c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, webforms

I want to find whether a text is present in the uploaded PDF file in ASP.NET c#.

```
using (MemoryStream str = new MemoryStream(this.docUploadField.FileBytes))
{
                    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(str, Encoding.UTF8))
                    {                       
                        string line = sr.ReadToEnd();
                    }
}
```

I am getting the below as the file content when I read the contents of file.

[image]

Please help me with this

Comment: It sounds like you're looking for a library to read PDF files.  There are many to choose from, your favorite search engine can help you find them.

Answer (score 1):

You surely need some PDF reading library.
Most famous being

IText (ITextSharp for who remembers it): https://github.com/itext/itext7-dotnet

PdfSharp: https://github.com/empira/PDFsharp

and many other free options.

With those you open pdf file and read it and take the text you need.
Usually they give you a collection of the PDF elements (paragraphs, images, etc etc, and you loop through them or use a search function to look for what you need)

Comment: ghostscript.net also has quite a good pdf text extractor. But, as you note, one needs some kind of library to do this, and PDF sharp is one such choice.